# How do I merge near rows based on column values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine that I have a table like this

| Start (day) | End (day) | Duration (days) | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 8 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 9 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 9 | 15 | 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 15 | 16 | 1 | 3 | 2 |

I want to merge near rows that has the same status. I want to let the start day being the start day of the first row of the sequence and the end day being the one of the last row. I also need to have the duration and the count summed, so in this example, I would want this result with the three last rows merged.

| Start (day) | End (day) | Duration (days) | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 8 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 16 | 8 | 3 | 9 |

How should I do this?

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `cumsum` trick with `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.agg`:

```
m = df["Status"].ne(df["Status"].shift()).cumsum()

new_df = df.groupby(m, as_index=False).agg({"Start (day)": "first", 
                                            "End (day)": "last",
                                            "Duration (days)": "sum", 
                                            "Status": "first", 
                                            "Count": "sum"})
```

Output:

```
   Start (day)  End (day)  Duration (days)  Status  Count
0            1          2                1       1      3
1            2          4                2       2      4
2            4          5                1       3      2
3            5          8                3       2      1
4            8         16                8       3      9
```